# Survival analysis: why MEDIAN of third event outcome is NA always?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

I am doing a survival analysis integrating gene expression based on normalized counts: a gene can be expressed at 'low', 'high', 'med' levels.

Here is what I do:

```
s <- survfit(Surv(clinical_data$days_to_death[ind_clin],as.numeric(clinical_data$Dead.alive[ind_clin])) ~ (event_rna[ind_gene,ind_tum]))
s1 <- tryCatch(survdiff(Surv(clinical_data$days_to_death[ind_clin],as.numeric(clinical_data$Dead.alive[ind_clin]))~event_rna[ind_gene,ind_tum]),error = function(e) return(NA))
```

where event_rna is a matrix of values 'low', 'med', 'high' with gene names as rownames.

Example:

```
> table(event_rna[ind_gene,ind_tum])

high  low  med 
   2    6   11
```

I always get the following:

```
                                  records n.max n.start events   *rmean *se(rmean) median 0.95LCL
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=high       2     2       2      1 1685.500  1144.4523     67      67
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=low        6     6       6      3 2347.600   472.2651   2161    2161
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=med       11    11      11      5 2006.011   429.9114     NA     662
```

The third variable 'med' gets NA in the median column.

Why could that be? Maybe because the event has 3 outcomes instead of being binary and I have to modify something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your data and code correctly, then the third outcome is the only one, for which <50% of records have an event. Without further assumptions (e.g. that some specific parametric distribution applies) it is then not possible to give a point estimate for the median time to event (the time when half the records have an event).